# Image of matrices to prove a matrix equality

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, matrix-equations, block-matrices

In a paper, they say that:
Since $\textrm{Im}(M^\top) \subseteq  \textrm{Im}[A^\top \quad B^\top]$, then

$$ M \bigg(-I + \begin{bmatrix}
A\\
B
\end{bmatrix}^\top 
\bigg(
\begin{bmatrix}
A\\
B
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
A\\
B
\end{bmatrix}^\top
\bigg)^\dagger 
\begin{bmatrix}
A\\
B
\end{bmatrix}
\bigg)
M^\top=0$$

I would like to kindly ask the following.

1. How can I understand the image of a matrix is a subset of the image of another matrix as the assumption here.
2. How can I prove the equality above.

Comment: Let $P=\begin{bmatrix}A\\ B\end{bmatrix}$. Since $\operatorname{Im}(M^\top)\subseteq\operatorname{Im}(P^\top)$, we have $M^\top=P^\top X$ for some matrix $X$. The equality now follows from the property of Moore-Penrose pseudo-inverse that $YY^+Y=Y$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $U = \begin{bmatrix} A^\top & B^\top \end{bmatrix}$. Then the claim becomes "$\text{Im}(M^\top) \subseteq \text{Im}(U)$ implies $M(-I + U(U^\top U)^\dagger U^\top)M^\top = 0$."

"$\text{Im}(M^\top) \subseteq \text{Im}(U)$" means that each column of $M^\top$ can be written as a linear combination of columns of $U$. In particular, this implies the existence of a matrix $V$ such that $M^\top = UV$. So, the equation can be rewritten as
$$V^\top U^\top (-I + U(U^\top U)^\dagger U^\top) UV = 0$$
$$V^\top (-U^\top U + U^\top U(U^\top U)^\dagger U^\top U) V = 0$$

The middle term above is zero, since a property of the [Moore-Penrose inverse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore%E2%80%93Penrose_inverse) is that $(U^\top U)(U^\top U)^\dagger U^\top U = U^\top U$.

Comment: Thank you very much!